# Foreign Key Violation In Prisma Migration with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-migration, prisma, blitz.js

I have a project using Prisma with PostgreSQL. I am trying to write a migration that inserts some data. The table has a foreign key to another table. The data I am inserting has a valid foreign key (the values are present in the database). However, when executing the migration, I am getting the error:

```
Error: P3006

Migration `20230922143649_test_prompt_creation` failed to apply cleanly to the shadow database.
Error:
insert or update on table "Prompt" violates foreign key constraint "Prompt_topicId_fkey"
   0: sql_schema_connector::validate_migrations
           with namespaces=None
             at schema-engine\connectors\sql-schema-connector\src\lib.rs:301
   1: schema_core::state::DevDiagnostic
             at schema-engine\core\src\state.rs:266
```

This is the migration script:

```sql
INSERT INTO
    "Prompt"("title", "desc", "seed", "promptHint", "topicId")
VALUES
    (
        '[REDACTED]',
        '[REDACTED]',
        '[REDACTED]',
        '[REDACTED]',
        2 -- Row in table Topic with id 2 exists
    );
```

Running this script directly against the database succeeds.

**Any ideas why applying this migration via Prisma fails?** I'm assuming it has something to do with the shadow database... One item to note is the Topic rows were created via a seed file, and not a migration, which may be a problem. I am not familiar with how the shadow database works.

I have tried working with ChatGPT to investigate potential solutions, googling for similar issues, reviewed some Issues on the Prisma GitHub, and searched StackOverflow for similar issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure that this is caused by the Shadow Database. From the [Prisma documentation](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-migrate/shadow-database):

`The shadow database is created and deleted automatically* each time you run a development-focused command and is primarily used to detect problems such as schema drift.`

In my case, we had created this data in a seeds file, which can be run by Blitz.JS. If we had put this data into a migration, it would have been present when the Shadow Database was recreated, and our migration would have succeeded.

**Moral of the story:** Don't use Blitz.JS' seeds functionality: put it all in DB migrations.

Answer (score -1):

try this. it should work

INSERT INTO "Topic"("id", "other_columns")
VALUES
(2, '[REDACTED]'),
-- Add more rows as needed
(3, '[REDACTED]');

INSERT INTO
"Prompt"("title", "desc", "seed", "promptHint", "topicId")
VALUES
(
'[REDACTED]',
'[REDACTED]',
'[REDACTED]',
'[REDACTED]',
2 -- Referencing the existing Topic with id 2
);

Comment: @Mubben Siddiqui Thanks, but I already have a row with Topic.id = 2. Which is why I am confused why the migration doesn't work